# matrix gradient of the Hadamard product

Tags: vector-analysis, matrix-calculus, hadamard-product

What is the matrix gradient  for the function $||A(B \circ X) ||_F^2 $  with respect to $X$. Here $A,B \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ and $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$.($\circ$) is the Hadamard product and Frobenius norm is used.

Answer (score 1):

Define the matrix 
$$Y=A(B\circ X)$$
Write the norm in terms of this new matrix and find its differential and gradient
$$\eqalign{
 \phi &= Y:Y \cr
d\phi
 &= 2Y:dY \cr
 &= 2Y:A(B\circ dX) \cr
 &= 2B\circ(A^TY):dX \cr
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial X}
 &= 2B\circ(A^TY) \cr
 &= 2B\circ(A^TA(B\circ X)) \cr
}$$
In some of the steps, a colon is used to denote the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$$A:B = {\rm tr}(A^TB)$$